# Kotlin inline functions and Android methods count

Tags: java, android, compilation, kotlin, dex

I want to understand how inline functions impact `classes.dex` and count of methods at all. From my understanding inline function should have zero overhead over methods count. However APK analyzer gives me opposite result.
I wrote small test to check this.

`InlineFunction.kt` file:

```
inline fun inlined(block: () -> Unit) {
    block()
}
```

And `MainActivity.kt` file:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        inlined {
            println("Inlined")
        }
    }
}
```

From perspective of generated code it looks pretty clear:

```
public final class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private HashMap _$_findViewCache;

    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       String var2 = "Inlined";
       System.out.println(var2);
   }
```

As we can see there is no call of additional method. But if I open apk with analyzer I can see that this method impacts defined and references methpds count.

[image]

On the other hand Kotlin stdlib impacts only referenced methods count and does not defined ones.

[image]

So what am I missing? I can't find how any good source about inlining methods in Android and how it is impact performance as well as I can't find any documentation how dex methods count is calculated.

I found [Jake Wharton utility](https://github.com/JakeWharton/dex-method-list) but if it works correct than all methods from Kotlin library impacts methods count. And it also means that something wrong in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39635849/4727432

> ...Standard library is very small and many of its functions are inline-only which mean they don't exist past compilation and just become inline code. Proguard can take care of a lot as well...

So how does inline functions impact methods count? Any articles or posts which explain dex method counting process are welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kotlin generates real methods even when they are marked `inline` for calling from java, so they are still reflected in the dex count.

Where inlining helps is overhead-free lambdas. Normally every lambda is represented with at least a method (sometimes even a class) in each place of invocation. But inlined lambdas skip this overhead, thus not affecting the dex count.

> Standard library is very small and many of its functions are inline-only

The standard library uses a special trick (`@inlineOnly` annotation) for some methods to skip generating a method for an inline function (as I described above). But this annotation is internal in the `kotlin` package and cannot be used in normal code.

Comment: Great! Now it becomes clear for me. And also it greatly explains why lint warn about `inline` without lambda.